# Passing a (timestamp) as an argument for a REST GET API

Tags: javascript, sql, rest, vue.js

I have been trying to get resources using GET Request. You can see the actual Query here:

```
{ "success": true,"data": [
{
  "ID": 123
  "Code": "Test",
  "Enabled": true,
  "Flags": 0,
  "Niveau": 0,
  "SQL": "SELECT GEMEENTE.GM_ID,\r\n  GEMEENTE.GM_POSTNUMMER,\r\n  
  GEMEENTE.GM_DEELGEMEENTE,\r\n  GEMEENTE.GM_LAND_FK,\r\n  
LAND.LN_ACTIEF\r\nFROM GEMEENTE\r\n  LEFT JOIN LAND ON GEMEENTE.GM_LAND_FK = 
 LAND.LN_ID\r\nWhere GM_VERANDERDOP >=:ChangedOn",
  "Parameters": [
    "ChangedOn"
  ],
  "QueryType": 0
}]}
```

However I need to pass an Argument to the "Parameters" property so i can actually see the response data. I see "ChangedOn" is a the argument array I need to set to a date. I tried this: `http://localhost/A/B/server.fcgi/Query?Code=Test&Parameters="2015-07-05T22:16:18Z"`

I am working with javascript and vue.

Answer (score 0):

What are we looking at here? Is this the server code of your API. In that case, it looks like you need to supply a ChangedOn parameter. Also, your query string should be url encoded. Try calling...

```
http://localhost/A/B/server.fcgi/Query?Code=Test&ChangedOn=22015-07-05T22%3A16%3A18Z
```

Comment: yes! This is the URL to access the API. I tried :http://localhost/A/B/server.fcgi/Query?Code=Test&ChangedOn=22015-07-05T22%3A16%3A18Z
but doesnt seem to pass the timestamp parameter to "changedOn".